# How to make horizontal Linear Layout Child wrap its content?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

As the title suggests in my case the child view is a `TextView` with some content. and I want it to be one per line

So putting `layout_width` to `0dp` and adding `layout_weight` to `1` did not work, Im assuming that because its the only one in its line so `1` is the highest wight... not sure about it though

this is the xml:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tagsVerticalLineup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
         />

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
         />

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
         />

    </LinearLayout>
```

At the end I want them one after another vertically (one on each row)
with horizontal size as their text length (content)

Is this even possible with `Linear Layout`?

Thanks

**EDIT**: 
As  @Ajil O answer is working, my own problem still remains. I isolated the main difference.

In my project Im adding the `Text View`s from the code using `Inflate` because I have default styling.

Inflating Code:

```
    final LinearLayout tagAreaView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tagsVerticalLineup);
    TextView tag = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.answer_tag, null);

    int tagId = someListArray.size();
    tag.setId(tagId);
    tag.setText(someChangingObject.text);
    tagAreaView.addView(tag, tagId);
```

Text View `answer_tag`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/SelectedTagAnswer" />
```

style xml `SelectedTagAnswer`:

```
<style name="SelectedTagAnswer">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/selected_answer</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:drawableStart">@drawable/ic_cross_round</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
</style>
```

**NOTE**:

When inserting a simple `Text View` to xml that uses same style, 
it works like in @Ajil O answer. Some thing in the inflating process messing it up.

Comment: I think changing the width of all the TextViews to wrap_content should solve your problem.

Comment: use wrap_content with width parameter. but it's size will increase horizontally as the text limit increase.

Comment: Mehul Kanzariya No, I was trying it before reading about `weight` solution, which also not working for me

Comment: you want the size to increase with text length horizontally but the text should remain in one line ?

Comment: Umair hard coding the width also not working... I dont care if the text will break to new line. at this point non works. at the end ill render simple html there and would like to break line at some size, but this is outside scope at this point

Comment: @darthydarth I have tried your code and now i have three textviews aligned vertically and their size increases horizontally as the length increase. I found your question quite confusing ;)

Comment: didnt understand your question? If u want the textview to have only one line, use  maxLines=1.

Comment: Jerin A Mathews don't really matter just want the width to be the length of the text (its short)

Comment: @Mahozad this question seems different than that.  This is a vertical layout wrapping the horizontal size of its children, not wrapping children around to another line when there's no more room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution, So turns out Android wont refresh layout of views with `wrap_content` once it has been displayed.

As found in this answer [WRAP_CONTENT not working after dynamically adding views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22821933/5674583)

So my problem was inflating the view and then adding content (text).

To over come that, I set again the the height and width like so:

```
    tag.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Now, if all from [Ajil O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47204757/5674583) answer is implemented, it is working!

Hope this edge case will come handy to someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

Make the `LinearLayout` width to `match_parent` and height to `wrap_content`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tagsVerticalLineup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want the `TextView` to occupy 1 line use `android:maxLines="1"` attribute

**EDIT**

[image]

The `TextView` are all in color now. You can see that the `TextView` is as wide as it's content.

The container, `LinearLayout` is shaded in the light violet(?) color. This `LinearLayout` has to be **atleast** as wide as the **longest** `TextView` or the view (or it's content) would get clipped.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tagsVerticalLineup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#AAAAFF"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#080"
        android:text="small text"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Slightly longer text"
        android:background="#400"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="loooooooooooooooooong text"
        android:background="#008"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @darthydarth Are you sure you are looking at the latest edit? What output are you getting at this point and how do you require it?

Comment: getting the `Text View`s stretch full width of device/linear layout and height of `Linear Layout` is as the `Text View` content. in short - full width and squished vertically

Comment: @darthydarth In that case I don't see why [Umair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47204670/6891637)'s answer does not work for you. In my answer the TextView will not expand to width of the `LinearLayout` (unless the text is long, ofc).

Comment: In this answer `Text View` are still stretching full width. in Umair's answer they all stretch to the size of the `Text View` width the longest text which is also not good. Maybe there is no good solution with `Linear Layout` but I cant use constraints.... feeling hopeless

Comment: @darthydarth Just to get some clarity, how wide do you want the `TextView` to actually go

Comment: Ajil O the width of its text (content). lets assume its no more the 2-4 short words to simplify the problem

Comment: @darthydarth I have added an image in the answer. The `TextView` **IS** as wide as it's content. I don't understand what your requirement is

Comment: I see, for some reason I'm not getting the same result, trying to understand why

Comment: I voted up because this works for the question I published for next ppl to come. but in my project it is still not working, there are more complexity there.. Thanks anyway

Comment: @darthydarth If you post in more detail there is a good chance some one might be able to help

Comment: Ajil O updated my question with more details from my own project

Answer (score 0):

Just use `wrap_content` parameter in your `android:layout_width`and you will be fine You are using `0dp` now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tagsVerticalLineup"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is ok but in my case I need the `Text View`s to wrap the their content, here they will be the size of the longest text

Comment: @darthydarth then you have 2 options either give hardcoded width to textview and the text will go down when size increase. if you want that too fixed then use maxlines="1" along with hardcoded width

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable that you use the ContrainstLayout and you can manipulate any event to the dimensions that you want

Comment: you are totally right but i can't in this case because I'm adding and removing the `Text View`s programmatically so constraints get messed up very quickly

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

- make the parent layout's `Height and Width=match_parent`
- `textView` make width `match_parent` so that you can use `textalignment=centre` or you can use `gravity=centre`

---

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tagsVerticalLineup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"     />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks I already figured it out, see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47207341/5674583