# TextView does not resize after TextSize is changed

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a `ConstraintLayout` with a `TextView` and `EditText` inside. The `TextView` is on the left, and when the `EditText` gains focus, I want the TextView to change its TextSize and move to the right. When it loses focus, I want to reverse that.

This is the Layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/custom_edit_text_constraint_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/custom_edit_text_text_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/custom_edittext_def_hint_margin"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/custom_edittext_def_hint_margin"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
    />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_edit_text_hint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/custom_edittext_def_hint_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/custom_edittext_def_hint_margin"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the code (If I forgot any important parts I can edit it):

```
hint = findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_text_hint);    //TextView
textField = findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_text_text_field);    //EditText
    textField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
                focusHint();
            } else {
                unfocusHint();
            }
        }
    });

private void focusHint() {
    hint.setTextSize(hintSizeFocused);
    hint.setTextColor(hintColorFocused);
    moveHintToRight();
}

private void unfocusHint() {
    hint.setTextColor(hintColor);
    if(textField.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        hint.setTextSize(hintSize);
        moveHintToLeft();
    }
}

private void moveHintToRight() {
    int horizontalDistance = textField.getWidth() - hint.getRight() - dpToPx(HINT_MARGIN_SIDE);
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, horizontalDistance, 0, 0);
    anim.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            ConstraintLayout l = findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_text_constraint_layout);
            ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
            set.clone(l);
            set.clear(R.id.custom_edit_text_hint, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
            set.connect(R.id.custom_edit_text_hint, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.custom_edit_text_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, dpToPx(HINT_MARGIN_SIDE));
            set.applyTo(l);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });
    hint.startAnimation(anim);
}

private void moveHintToLeft() {
    int horizontalDistance = - hint.getLeft() + dpToPx(HINT_MARGIN_SIDE);
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, horizontalDistance, 0, 0);
    anim.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
            ConstraintLayout l = findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_text_constraint_layout);
            set.clone(l);
            set.clear(R.id.custom_edit_text_hint, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
            set.connect(R.id.custom_edit_text_hint, ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.custom_edit_text_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.LEFT, dpToPx(HINT_MARGIN_SIDE));
            set.applyTo(l);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });
    hint.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

This works great, but only when I don't resize the TextSize of the `TextView`. When I resize the TextSize (as shown in the code), `hint.getLeft()` and `hint.getRight()` return the values, which the `TextView` would have with the old TextSize, and this results in that the `TextView` moves either too far or not far enought. But this doesn't make sense to me because I resize the TextSize BEFORE I start the animation and the `TextView`'s width is set to `wrap_content`. Does anyone have an idea why this doesn't work and how I can fix it?

**EDIT:**

To further explain and simplify what exactly the problem is, I have an example:

```
textView.setTextSize(12);
int width1 = hint.getWidth();
textView.setTextSize(18);
int width2 = hint.getWidth();
```

As the `TextView`'s width is set to `wrap_content`, the width should change when I change the textSize (at least I thought so). But width1 and width2 are the same. How can I fix that?

**EDIT2:**

I solved the problem with 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982632/wrap-content-not-working-after-dynamically-adding-views) by Eric.

Answer (score 0):

Add right and end constraint of the textview  as follows.If you want it to be in middle then set horizontal_bias = 0.5 or if you want it left then 0.0 and lastly in right 1.0

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/custom_edit_text_hint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/custom_edittext_def_hint_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/custom_edittext_def_hint_margin"
            android:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf = "parent"
            android:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
          />
```

Hope this will work.Try it

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the fixed position after the animation is right. What's wrong is the position where the `TextView` moves during the animation. It moves too far / not far enought, but when I set the new constraints, it is at the right position. So, what's wrong is the `horizontalDistance`

Comment: you can move it by changing the horizontal_bias from 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: I need to move it programmatically with an animation.

Comment: okay.. give me some time i will send you demo.. how to animate it programmatically. it wil be quite easy

Comment: I edited an example to better simplify my problem. Maybe you can help me now.